# How to remove elements with whitespace?

Tags: jquery

I can easily remove a tag that has no blank spaces...

```
$('h2:empty').remove();
```

But, when there is a space...

```
<h2> </h2>
```

...this does not work.

I tried

```
if ($('h2').html() == " "){
    $('h2').remove(); 
}
```

Also no luck. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$("h2").each(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   if ( self.html().trim().length == 0 )
   {
     self.remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Why would you use `filter()` instead of `each()`?

Comment: My mistake, but if you're using jQuery, you may as well use its cross-browser safe utilities. Although `String.prototype.trim()` is pretty well supported nowadays.

Answer (score 15):

You can match elements with only whitespace text with...

```
$('h2').filter(function() {
   return ! $.trim($(this).text());
});
```

To remove these elements, call `remove()` on the returned set.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwBqA/).

---

Alternatively, without jQuery...

```
elements.filter(function(element) {
    return ! (element.textContent || element.innerText).replace(/\s+/g, '');
});
```

If your `elements` is a `HTMLCollection`, `NodeList` (or otherwise not an `Array`), use `Array.filter(elements, fn)` or turn `elements` into an `Array` with `Array.prototype.slice.call(elements)`.

If you didn't have to support older browsers too, you could use `return ! (element.textContent || element.innerText).trim()`.

To remove these, loop over the elements and use `thisElement.parentNode.removeChild(thisElement)`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evcnb/).

---

Alternatively, with working with nodes only...

```
var containsWhitespace = function me(node) {
    var childNodes = node.childNodes;

    if (childNodes.length == 0) {
        return true;    
    }

    for (var i = 0, length = childNodes.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
            return me(childNodes[i]);
        } else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
            return ! childNodes[i].data.replace(/\s+/g, '');   
        }
    }
}

elements.filter(containsWhitespace);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRmMr/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use jQuery, but I can give a straight JavaScript solution:

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('h2'), l = elms.length, i;
for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if( elms[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/,"") == "") {
        elms[i].parentNode.removeChild(elms[i]);
    }
}
```

So just do whatever the jQuery equivalent is, I guess.

Comment: `/\s+/,""` - that's the key OP. It's a regular expression, it replaces whitespace with.. nothing.

Comment: This will have a problem though if the OP's `h2` element may include descendent elements.

Answer (score 1):

To adapt on alex's, try this:

```
$('h2').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0;
}).remove();
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/zTrtf/).

Comment: This is just a more *explicit* version of mine. Mine relies on the fact an empty string is *falsy* in JavaScript. Being explicit is helpful too though, it is probably clearer.

Comment: I very much enjoyed your answer.  Never knew I could just do return ! $.trim($(this).text());

Answer (score 0):

This will only check for one space, but works for a basic example:

```
$("h2:contains(' ')").remove()
```