# Remove empty tags in a HTML doc with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove empty p tags using jquery.

I've written the following only it doesn't seem to work.

```
      $( 'p:empty' ).remove();
```

Here's a live demo...

http://jsfiddle.net/CuJXG/

Comment: In your example "<p>" isn't empty.  It has white space characters in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924268/how-to-remove-elements-with-whitespace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

That's because your element isn't empty.

Do this :

```
$('p').filter(function(){return $(this).text().trim().length==0}).remove();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7qDdV/)

As noted by wirey, to make it work on IE8, you should do this :

```
$('p').filter(function(){return $.trim($(this).text()).length==0}).remove();
```

Comment: string.trim() will break in IE8 and earlier.. should use $.trim(string) or regex instead

Comment: This won't work if a `<p>` tag has an `img` tag inside it. It will remove it. So be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Your example has whitespaces inside `<p>` tag, remove them and it will work. To be more consistent, just write your own filter function, like dystroy suggests.