# Filter text from variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, filter, tags

I'm working with CKEditor and have created a `Post` button to post what the user types in the editor. I want the `Post` button to be disabled or enabled based on whether actual text has been typed in the editor. However, if the user just clicks on form elements (**`B`**, *`I`*, etc) without typing, the DOM fills up with empty tags like this: `<strike><b></b><i></i></strike>`. This causes my parser to interpret the textarea as having text when I do this check:

```js
    this.textData = $('.noteEditor1').ckeditorGet().getSnapshot()
                                                .replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n")
                                                .replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
    //if there is no style on the text, $(this.textData).text() will be an empty string, so make sure it contains brackets and isn't empty
    // before using it
    if(this.textData.indexOf('<') !== -1 && this.textData.indexOf('>') !== -1 && $(this.textData).text() !== "") {
        this.textData = $(this.textData).text();
    }
    //have to remove zero width spaces characters so they aren't counted in the text length
    var text = this.textData.replace(/[\n?\r?\t?]/g, "")
                            .replace(/[\u200B-\u200D\uFEFF]/g, '');

    if(text.length > 0) {
        $('.footer-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('.footer-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
```

I found this jQuery filter on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882245/remove-empty-tags-in-a-html-doc-with-jquery) which I think will do what I want when I put multiple selectors in it.

```js
$('b, i, u, strike, sub, sup').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim().length===0;
}).remove();
```

How do I get this filter to run on my variable, `this.textData`?

**EDIT !IMPORTANT**

I added the rest of the function because it looks like the problem comes from that `if` statement. I have to do that check because if I don't, then text that doesn't have any style gets stripped. However, with it I end up *not* using `$(this.textData).text()` when I just have empty tags, which means that the tags stick around, hence I have to filter them. How can I make sure I don't clear out unformatted text but still clear out empty formatting tags?

I tried using the filter above like this:

```js
$(text).find('b, i, u, strike, sub, sup').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().trim().length===0;
}).remove();
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the value of `this.textData` ?

Comment: What is textData. What does it have?

Comment: According to the minimal example you provided this ''should'' be working. http://jsfiddle.net/ANtKJ/

Comment: My example is the empty tags `<strike><b></b><i></i></strike>`.

Comment: See if this works for you `$('b:empty, i:empty, u:empty, strike:empty, sub:empty, sup:empty',$(this.textData)).remove();` You dont have to use filter

Comment: I added some more information about what's in the class and where the problem might be coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, last shot

```
this.textData = $('.noteEditor1').ckeditorGet().getSnapshot();
var text =  $.trim($(this.textData).text()); 

if(text.length > 0) {
    $('.footer-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
    $('.footer-btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Comment: As I said in my revised answer, I can't always use `$(this.textData).text()` because it strips out text when there are no style tags.

Comment: What about cheating a little bit? -> `$('<div>' + this.textData + '</div>').text()`

Comment: Oh snap, that might do it!