# How to remove all empty or space div on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple basic html structure

```
<div class="fl-no-pad" style="display: block;">


 </div>
```

as you see this div is empty or has space.how can I remove all theese div in this case ?

and this is my jquery code

```
$(".fl-no-pad").each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')){
        $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Just as a side note (maybe for futur readers), CSS4 would handle it using [:blank pseudo class](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/blank-pseudo-class/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove elements with whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924268/how-to-remove-elements-with-whitespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in jQuery. This way you can set your own definition for "empty".

```js
$(function() {
  var empties = $('div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().trim() == '';
  });
  
  alert(empties.length);
  empties.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fl-no-pad" style="display: block;">


 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To conform to futur [CSS4 spec](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/blank-pseudo-class/), you could extend jQuery pseudo selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    blank: function(elm) {
        return !$(elm).html().trim().length;
    }
});
```

Then use:

```
$('div:blank').remove();
```

In CSS4 only, you could not display element instead:

```
div:blank { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like :

```
if( !$.trim( $(this).html() ).length ) {
  //do something
}
```