# How to trim html content in js?

Tags: javascript

I have a contenteditable div and I would like to remove empty lines and spaces at the beginning and the end before sending his content to server. I have read some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924268/how-to-remove-elements-with-whitespace) but don't find what I want. I would like to do the same as `trim` function by deleting spaces(as `nbsp;`) at the begenning and at the end but also delete empty lines(which mean empty block as `<div></div>` or `<br>` or `<div><br></div>` and so on...)

Here is some examples:

```
<div><br></div><div>Hello</div><div>World</div><div><br></div></div>
```

Should be

```
<div>Hello</div><div>World</div>
```

And also

```
&nbsp;<div><br></div><div>Hello</div><div></div><div>World</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Should be

```
<div>Hello</div><div></div><div>World</div>
```

And so on...

How to do this please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove elements with whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924268/how-to-remove-elements-with-whitespace)

Comment: @JosephSible it is a little bit different

Comment: Why is a `<div></div>` removed in the first example, but not the second?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry I don't speak english well ! As you said I want to remove all divs that aren't between words which means at the begenning and at the end

Comment: @AmadouBeye The idea is: `remove empty tags(or with <br> inside), but not in between the tags(<div>text</div>between<div></div>still between<div>end between</div>) that have some content`, right?

Comment: @AmadouBeye, what have you tried so far? Any attempt?

Comment: @BladeMight exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what are you looking for, using `for loop`, `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` properties.

```js
function trimHTML(t) {
  var between = false;
  var outHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < t.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var lt = t.childNodes[i];
    //console.log(lt.innerHTML)
    var nowset = false;
    if (lt.innerHTML != undefined && lt.innerHTML != "" && lt.innerHTML != "<br>") {
      between = !between;
      nowset = true;
      outHTML += lt.outerHTML;
    }
    if (between && !nowset) {
      outHTML += lt.outerHTML;
    }
  }
  return outHTML;
}

var t = document.querySelector("#t");
var result = document.querySelector("#result");
t.innerHTML = "<div></div><div></div><div><br></div><div>Hello</div><div>World</div><div><br></div></div>";
result.value = "---TEST1: \nfrom:\n" + t.innerHTML + "\nto:\n" + trimHTML(t);
t.innerHTML = "&nbsp;<div><br></div><div>Hello</div><div></div><div>World</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
result.value += "\n---TEST2: \nfrom:\n" + t.innerHTML + "\nto:\n" + trimHTML(t);
```

```html
<div id="t">
</div>
<textarea id="result" style="width: 100%;min-height:90px;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: It does not remove empty divs (which does'nt have text content) at the begenning and the end

Comment: @AmadouBeye Are you sure? If you run this code snippet, it will output: that it converted the: `<div></div><div></div><div><br></div><div>Hello</div><div>World</div><div><br></div>` to `<div>Hello</div><div>World</div>`, all tabs that are empty or contain the `<br>` are not included.

Comment: @AmadouBeye Here is the same snippet on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fua0skgm/).

Comment: yes I can see. I have a little troube to make it work with a contenteditable div ! I will try to fix it ! Thank you so much

Comment: @AmadouBeye Goodluck :)